# How to save dropdownlist selected value to the database int asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am currently new to Asp.net MVC .In one of the view I add a dropdownlist and I bind this dropdownlist with my database like this

Controller `CollegeController`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.College_Names.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.id.ToString(), Text = c.Name });
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> item = db.Stream_Names.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.id.ToString(), Text = c.Stream });
    ViewBag.CollName=items;
    ViewBag.StreamName = item;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(College college)
{
    try
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Colleges.Add(college);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.CollName = db.Colleges;
        return View(college);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is my model

```
public class College
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="College Name")]
    public int CollegeName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Stream { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName="varchar")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ....
    public virtual College_Name College_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Stream_Name Stream_Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is My View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CollegeName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("CollName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CollName, "Select College", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CollegeName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Stream, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("StreamName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StreamName, "Select Stream", new { @class = "form-control" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Stream, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when I check my database after I save the `CollegeName` and `Stream` in the database is zero from the dropdownlist.

Comment: That's a lot of code included. If you could update the question to include the minimum amount of code needed to show the problem you have you might have a larger chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems with your code. Firstly you dropdownlists are binding to a properties named `CollName` and `StreamName` which do not even exist in your model.

Next you cannot name the property your binding to the same as the `ViewBag` property.

Your view code would need to be (and **always** use the strongly typed `xxxFor()` `HtmHelper` methods

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CollegeName, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CollName, "Select College", new { @class = "form-control" })
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Stream, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StreamName, "Select Stream", new { @class = "form-control" }
```

and in your POST method, the values of `college.CollegeName` and `college.Stream` will contain the ID's of the selected options.

You also need to repopulate the `ViewBag` properties when you return the view in the POST method (as you did in the GET method) or an exception will be thrown (and note that your current use of `ViewBag.CollName = db.Colleges;` will also throw an exception)

I also strongly suggest you start learning to use view models (views for editing should not use data models - refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)) - and use naming conventions that reflect what your properties are, for example `CollegeNameList`, or `CollegeNames`, not `CollName`